# Drop down value change on clicking prev and next button in angular 2

Tags: angular

i want to display the current year as default date in drop down and when prev button is clicked it should decrease the year by one and also it should affect  selected year value in drop down in Angular 2

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>Select demo</h2>
    <a (click)="changeYear()">Prev</a>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedyear" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
      <option *ngFor="let c of year" [ngValue]="c"> {{c}} </option>
    </select>
  `
})
class App {
  year  = ['2016','2015','2014'];

  selectedyear ;

  onChange(year) {
    alert(year);
    this.selectedyear = year;
  }

  changeYear(){
    this.selectedyear = this.selectedyear -1;
    this.onChange(this.selectedyear);

  }
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you click previous button after 2014, it will be 2013 which you don't have it inside the array year.

so whenever you decrease check if the element exists inside the array, if not push inside the array.

```
 changeYear(){
    this.selectedyear = this.selectedyear -1;
    this.year.push(this.selectedyear); 
  }
```

*[**`DEMO`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZitFhyfRmrowKULYIDsZ?p=preview)*

Comment: its a sample , even if i selected ,it is not affecting in drop down

Comment: check it again it does

Comment: how to make a default value in that drop downwhen it loads

Comment: just set the selectedyear = '2015' ;

Comment: it should be  selectedyear not  sselectedyear, check the demo